# ReactJs Select V3 not updating options disable status on dynamically changing options isDisabled status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, react-select

I am **dynamically generating select boxes** all select boxes have same options but when I select one option it gets disabled in all other select boxes, this works fine when I add select boxes one by one or select value of each select box one by one line vise and update state of options. But when I **remove select box** I enable previous selected option and disable currently selected option and then update the state of options but in UI disabled option is not reflecting properly while if I inspect that component its state is working correctly and showing correct results but view of component is not showing result according to options disabled status.

[image: This is flow of my select boxes]

Below is my select onChange Event handler and Remove Question Event Handler:

```
handleAddQuestion(){
    const values = [...this.state.selectedQuestions];
    values.push({ question: { value : '', label : ''}, answer: '' });
    const addCounter = this.state.addCounter + 1;
    this.setState({ selectedQuestions : values, addCounter : addCounter });
}

handleDynamicDropDown(index, event){
    const values = [...this.state.selectedQuestions];
    const prevQues = values[index].question;
    console.log(values,index,event);
    values[index].question = event;
    values[index].answer = '';
    
    const viewQuestionsList = this.state.viewQuestionsList;
    const selectedIndex = this.selectedQuestionIndex(event.value, this.state.viewQuestionsList, this.state.viewQuestionsList.length);
    viewQuestionsList[selectedIndex].isDisabled = true
    
    if(prevQues.value){
        var prevIndex = this.selectedQuestionIndex(prevQues.value, this.state.viewQuestionsList, this.state.viewQuestionsList.length)
        viewQuestionsList[prevIndex].isDisabled = null;
    }
    this.forceUpdate();
    this.setState({ selectedQuestions : values, viewQuestionsList : viewQuestionsList });
     this.forceUpdate();
}

selectedQuestionIndex(id, arr, arrLen){
    for(var i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
        if(arr[i].value === id) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my component:

```
{this.state.selectedQuestions.map((fields, index) => ( 
   <div className="d-flex" key={index}>
     <div className="flex-fill w-50">
        {fields.question.value && 
          <Form.Dropdown 
              label={`Question ${index+1}`}                                                                       
              onChange={(event) => this.handleDynamicDropDown(index, event)}                                                                           
              inputClassName="form-group"                                                                          
              placeholder="Select Question"                                                                           
              messageField="Question
              isSearchable={true}
              name="question"                                                      
              value={fields.question}                                                     
              fluid                                                      
              search
              selection                                                                      
              options={this.state.viewQuestionsList}
          />
```

Comment: just add some dynamic `key` to the react-select which will trigger select update

Comment: `<Select key={dynamicKey} ...`. It could be previous select value

Comment: @demkovych doing this still doesn't resolves my issue.